# it is possible to upgrade only php version php 7.4 to php 8.1 without upgrade Laravel version?

Tags: laravel-6, php-8.1

I want to upgrade only the PHP version for my Laravel project,

**My Laravel Framework version is  6.20.19 and PHP version is 7.4,**

now I want to upgrade only php version php 7.4 to PHP 8.1 for my current Laravel project,
how can I do without upgrading the Laravel version?

I have configured PHP 8.1 in my Linux System and configured my Laravel 6.20 version project, and made some changes in **composer.json**.

```
"require": {
        "php": "^8.1",
```

Now run the project, and get below a bunch of errors.

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1232

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1243

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1255

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Container\Container::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 1268

> Deprecated: Return type of Dotenv\Environment\AbstractVariables::offsetExists($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Environment/AbstractVariables.php on line 162

> Deprecated: Return type of Dotenv\Environment\AbstractVariables::offsetGet($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Environment/AbstractVariables.php on line 170

> Deprecated: Return type of Dotenv\Environment\AbstractVariables::offsetSet($offset, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Environment/AbstractVariables.php on line 178

> Deprecated: Return type of Dotenv\Environment\AbstractVariables::offsetUnset($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Environment/AbstractVariables.php on line 186

> Deprecated: Return type of PhpOption\None::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/phpoption/phpoption/src/PhpOption/None.php on line 118

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php on line 355

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php on line 345

> Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ParameterBag.php on line 213

> Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/ParameterBag.php on line 223

> Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/HeaderBag.php on line 282

> Deprecated: Return type of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag::count() should either be compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/HeaderBag.php on line 292

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Http\Request::offsetExists($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php on line 641

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Http\Request::offsetGet($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php on line 655

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Http\Request::offsetSet($offset, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php on line 667

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Http\Request::offsetUnset($offset) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php on line 678

> Deprecated: strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Request.php on line 295

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 141

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 152

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 164

> Deprecated: Return type of Illuminate\Config\Repository::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/MyProject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php on line 175

Comment: Let's check laravel requirements: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/composer.json. Yep, it possible for laravel, but your other packages can be not compatible with php8.